# Hi, is it possible to use a cropper for pdf in angular?

Tags: pdf, cropper

i search everywhere but no one can help me.
I need to crop a pdf file using some library for angual 10 or more

i have allready try ngx-image-cropper but it can't be use for pdf files

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to crop a pdf directly. You can to convert the pdf to an image and then you can to crop it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

PDF cropping is not trivial, since a PDF crop boundary is simply the edge of the viewport so you can easily reset it inside the /Mediabox (even simply rename them) but it should never crop the contents. Here we see the Text now runs off the page boundary,

[image]

Thus when asking for a crop tool many users actually need a redaction tool, that cuts away the unwanted external edges, or is highly variable to only encompass the page contents, which for images is not likely to be practical using a programmed approach, thus best done using a GUI like BRISS